# CSS: Z-Index Stacking Context

Tags: html, css

I have been met with a bit of surprise today, I have the bellow HTML markup.
In my CSS I set the container to `position: fixed; z-index: 3`, and then I provided a z-index of 1 to `div#1` and `div#3` giving `div#2` `z-index: 2`. My expectation is that when I move `div#3` up that it will go behind `div#2` but to my greatest surprise it always stays above it no matter the value of its z-index or that of `div#2`, I am confused why this is, maybe I don't just understand the stacking context as much as I think I do. Any help? Below I have the css.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html, .container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 300;
}

#div1, #div2, #div3 {
  opacity: 0.7;
  padding: 10px;
}

#div1 {
  border: 1px dashed #996;
  background-color: #ffc;
  height: 33.333%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#div2 {
  border: 1px dashed #900;
  background-color: #fdd;
  height: 33.333%;
  z-index: 2;
}

#div3 {
  border: 1px dashed #696;
  background-color: #cfc;
  height: 33.333%;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY(-40px)
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div id="div1">DIV#1 </div>
  <div id="div2">DIV#2</div>
  <div id="div3">DIV#3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your element need to be at least `position:relative` to use z-index as this property doesn't work with static position (the default value)

as you can read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) :

> Note: z-index only works on **positioned elements** (position:absolute,
>   position:relative, or position:fixed).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html, .container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 300;
}

#div1, #div2, #div3 {
  position:relative;
  opacity: 0.7;
  padding: 10px;
}

#div1 {
  border: 1px dashed #996;
  background-color: #ffc;
  height: 33.333%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#div2 {
  border: 1px dashed #900;
  background-color: #fdd;
  height: 33.333%;
  z-index: 2;
}

#div3 {
  border: 1px dashed #696;
  background-color: #cfc;
  height: 33.333%;
  z-index: 3;
  transform: translateY(-40px)
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div id="div1">DIV#1 </div>
  <div id="div2">DIV#2</div>
  <div id="div3">DIV#3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to *create a stacking context* using the `z-index` property, the element in question must be a **positioned element**.

> The `z-index` CSS property specifies the z-order of a positioned element
>   and its descendants.

Ref: [z-index -CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Positioned elements are any elements with a `position` property declared, other than `static`; which is the *default positioning* of any element.

**Example of *positioned* elements:**

1. `relative` (relative)
2. `absolute` (absolute)
3. `fixed` (absolute)
4. `sticky` (stickily)

Ref: [position -CSS | MDN (Types of positioning)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Types_of_positioning)

To demonstrate this, declare `relative` positioning on the nested `div` elements of the containing parent element `.container`, e.g:

```
.container > div {
  position: relative;
}
```

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
/* Additional */

.container > div {
  position: relative;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html, .container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
}

#div1, #div2, #div3 {
  opacity: 0.7;
  padding: 10px;
}

#div1 {
  border: 1px dashed #996;
  background-color: #ffc;
  height: 33.333%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#div2 {
  border: 1px dashed #900;
  background-color: #fdd;
  height: 33.333%;
  z-index: 2;
}

#div3 {
  border: 1px dashed #696;
  background-color: #cfc;
  height: 33.333%;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY(-40px)
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="div1">DIV#1 </div>
  <div id="div2">DIV#2</div>
  <div id="div3">DIV#3</div>
</div>
```

For further information: [Understanding CSS z-index - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index)

Answer (score 2):

add `position: relative` to the divs

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html, .container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 300;
}

#div1, #div2, #div3 {
  opacity: 0.7;
  padding: 10px;
}

#div1 {
  border: 1px dashed #996;
  background-color: #ffc;
  height: 33.333%;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

#div2 {
  border: 1px dashed #900;
  background-color: #fdd;
  height: 33.333%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

#div3 {
  border: 1px dashed #696;
  background-color: #cfc;
  height: 33.333%;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(-40px)
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div id="div1">DIV#1 </div>
  <div id="div2">DIV#2</div>
  <div id="div3">DIV#3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got it right, just add *position: relative;* to the elements so the z-index setting will take effect.

The z-index CSS property specifies the z-order of a positioned element and its descendants. [MDN - CSS z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) A positioned element is an element whose computed position value is either relative, absolute, fixed, or sticky. (In other words, it's anything except static.) [MDN - CSS position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html, .container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 300;
}

#div1, #div2, #div3 {
  opacity: 0.7;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

#div1 {
  border: 1px dashed #996;
  background-color: #ffc;
  height: 33.333%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#div2 {
  border: 1px dashed #900;
  background-color: #fdd;
  height: 33.333%;
  z-index: 2;
}

#div3 {
  border: 1px dashed #696;
  background-color: #cfc;
  height: 33.333%;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY(-40px);
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div id="div1">DIV#1 </div>
  <div id="div2">DIV#2</div>
  <div id="div3">DIV#3</div>
</div>
```